# Show the following matrix has determinant = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, determinant

I just faced this problem where i am asked to show this matrix has determinant = 0 and I got stuck and can't find a way out of this...would really appreciate if someone could help
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \alpha & \sin \alpha & \sin (\alpha + \theta) \\
\cos \beta & \sin \beta & \sin (\beta + \theta) \\
\cos \gamma & \sin \gamma & \sin (\gamma + \theta) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My attempt:
[image: my try]

Comment: Is "$\operatorname{sen}$" what most of us would call "$\sin$"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 4):

The third column is equal to $\sin\theta$ times the first column plus $\cos\theta$ times the second column, by the well-known formula
$$
\sin(u)\cos(v) + \cos(u)\sin(v) = \sin(u + v)
$$
This makes the columns linearly dependent and therefore the matrix is singular.

Comment: Really appreciate your fast reply....i was so focused in calculating the determinant I absolutely forgot about that...

Comment: If they had asked for any value other than $0$, then calculating the determinant and hoping to spot a whole lot of trigonometric identities to simplify it might have been the only way. As it happens, $0$ is a very special value when it comes to determinants, and therefore we have a lot of different ways to determine it.